# CSS Invalid Property Value (Bootstrap) - Font Hover Color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
a {
  color: #E0E0E0 !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #171F26B !important;
}
```

Currently trying to create my own website and I'm running with some troubles trying to get the navigation item hover to work. I keep coming up with 'Invalid Property Value'.

I've tried targeting several classes and tags in different ways, but it ultimately doesn't work. I've also tried being very specific as you can tell from the code above, however that isn't working either.

I understand that sometimes we may use !important to give a CSS property priority so it may override bootstrap.

Comment: Yep because #171F26B is not valid it contains 7 characters instead of the regular 6

Comment: make correction in `color` it should be `color: #171f26 !important;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a {
  color: #E0E0E0 !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #171F26B !important;
}
```

Reduce the color code by 1 on: `color: #171F26B !important;`

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in your color value. Hexadecimal colors have six letters; #171F26B has one letter too many.